# How to debug an hanging impdp importation

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, impdp

I am currently trying to import a database dump in Oracle XE 11gR2 On windows 7. I have the following command.

```
 impdp 'APPLICATION/APPLICATION@XE' dumpfile=APPLICATION.dmp REMAP_TABLESPACE=APPLICATION:USERS logfile=APPLICATIONIMPORT.log
```

I tried running the command in the windows command prompt but... nothing happens. The process does not exit or do anything. It print a copyright and just... hang without using any CPU or anything. The log file is not created, and SQL Developper show no import task when I query with `SELECT * FROM DBA_DATAPUMP_JOBS;`

I there anyway to see what is going on? Any log, table, place where an error could be outputted? That would really help me resolve this problem.

Note: If that can help, I am an administrator on my machine but part of a Windows Domain. It screwed up the Oracle XE install the first time but I got around by running the installer with a local admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with a weird fix : I removed the `'APPLICATION/APPLICATION@XE'` and entered the username/password manually with the interactive prompt.

I consulted this page: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump and realized that I was not getting an equivalent of this line `Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`, which tipped me it was a connection problem. By trying to remove the username/password from the command line it suddenly fixed the problem.

I am afraid I can't exactly say why this helped, but I hope this can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes around username/password should solve your problem.